# Can't get all documents from firebase collection with SnapshotListener

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I can get all documents from firebase with get() method which is not getting updates from Firestore but I can't get all documents with addSnapshotListener method. When I try to use this method it's throwing following exception :

> Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but Pairs has 1

Here is the code snippets :

with snapshot listener :

```
fun retrievePairsFromFirebase() {
        
        database.collection("Pairs").document(currentUserEmail!!).collection("Pair").addSnapshotListener { value, error ->

                if (error != null) {

                    println(error.localizedMessage)

                } else {
                    value!!.documents.forEach { documentSnapshot ->
                        if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {

                            val retreivedObj = documentSnapshot.toObject(PairListModel::class.java)

                            pairState.add(retreivedObj!!)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

with get method :

```
fun retrievePairsFromFirebase() {
        database.collection("Pairs").document(currentUserEmail!!).collection("Pair").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->

                if (querySnapshot.documents.isNotEmpty()) {
                    querySnapshot.documents.forEach {
                        val newPairObj = it.toObject(PairListModel::class.java)

                        pairState.add(newPairObj!!)
                    }
                } else {
                    println("veriler indirilemedi")
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like `currentUserEmail!!` has no value in your code. You'll want to check that before passing it to Firebase.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it has. When i tried the use `orderBy` method after collection problem is gone. But i can't find more elegant method.

Comment: Have you referred to this document: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen